# A continuous $f$ defined on $[c,b)$ is differentiable on $(c,b)$ and if $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)$ doesn't exist, $f$ is not differentiable at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis" (in Japanese) by Kunihiko Kodaira.

The following theorem is in this book:

> Theorem 3.10 (on p.125):
> If a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $[c,b)$ is differentiable on $(c,b)$ and if $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)$ exists, then $f(x)$ is differentiable at $c$ too and $$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x).$$

Does the following proposition hold or not?

> Proposition 1:
> If a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $[c,b)$ is differentiable on $(c,b)$ and if $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)$ doesn't exist, then $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $c$.

---

> Example 1:
> Let $f(x) = x^3$.
> Let $g(x) = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.
> Then, $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ but $f(g(x))=1$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

> Example 2:
> Let $f(x)=\log(x)$.
> Let $g(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$.
> Then, $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$ and $f(g(x))$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.
> $f(g(x))$ is differentiable on $(1,+\infty)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.
> $\lim_{x\to 1+0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ does not exist.
> So, if Proposition 1 holds, then by Proposition 1, $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))$ doesn't exist at $x=1$.
> In this case, we don't need to check $$\lim_{h\to +0} \frac{f(g(1+h))-f(g(1))}{h}$$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. Take $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Paul Frost, Thank you very much for your answer.