# A continuous $f$ defined on $[c,b)$ is differentiable on $(c,b)$ and if $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)=+\infty$, $f$ is not differentiable at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I asked the following question and Paul Frost answered my question.

[A continuous $f$ defined on $[c,b)$ is differentiable on $(c,b)$ and if $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)$ doesn't exist, $f$ is not differentiable at $c$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4423723/384082)

---

I want to ask a similar question:

Does the following proposition hold or not?

> Proposition 2:
> If a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $[c,b)$ is differentiable on $(c,b)$ and if $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)=+\infty$ or $\lim_{x\to c+0} f'(x)=-\infty$, then $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $c$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? – *Hint:* You can argue similarly as in these questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/257907?lq=1

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for your answer. The same proof works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advice for questions about derivatives**, i.e., functions that are everywhere in some interval the derivative of some other function.

These are elusive little devils.  As a calculus student you expect them to be continuous since you never see examples that are not continuous.  Then as an analysis student you see examples with a few discontinuities and wonder just how many discontinuities a derivative might have.  [A number of StackExchange questions on *that* topic.]

But the very first step in understanding derivatives is to have these first  two necessary conditions in mind:

1. If $f$ is a derivative on an interval $[a,b]$ then $f$ is a function in the first class of Baire (i.e., a Baire one function).
2. If $f$ is a derivative on an interval $[a,b]$ then $f$ is a Darboux function (i.e., $f$ has the intermediate value property, just like a continuous function has).
3. Those are necessary, but not sufficient conditions.  To learn more will take some considerable effort.  [See the monograph by Andy Bruckner, Differentiation of Real Functions, https://www.amazon.com/Differentiation-Real-Functions-Crm-Monograph/dp/0821869906  if you are serious about this subject.  Lots to learn.]

If you can remember just the first two statements here then questions of this type are trivial.

> **If an elementary level question asks you to prove that a function is *not* a derivative, suspect first of all that it is not a Darboux function.**

For the situation here:  If $f'(c) = L$ exists but $f'(x) > L+1$ for all $c<x<c+\delta$ for some $\delta>0$ then $f'$ cannot be a Darboux function.  If it is not a Darboux function it is not a derivative. **QED.**

Comment: B. S. Thomson, Thank you very much for your answer.